# Convert RDD Parquet from StreamingContext and textFileStream

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, parquet

I have a Streaming  PySpark job that reads new line delimited JSON and performes some aggregations and then saves them to some folders.

I want to change the files that are being streamd from JSON to parquet.

Here is how I create the context:

```py
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(
    master="local[5]", appName="parquet_job", conf=conf
)
DATA_PATH = "the_data_path"
BATCH_TIMEOUT = 10

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, BATCH_TIMEOUT)
sqlC = SQLContext(sc)

dstream = ssc.textFileStream(DATA_PATH)
```

next, everytime a new file is beeing read by Spark I do

```py
dstream.foreachRDD(parse_data)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
while not stopped:
    pass
ssc.stop()
sc.stop()
```

and `parse_data` is a function that performs multiple aggregations with different other functions.

Reading JSON files was OK. When I started reading parquet files nothing was working.

I tried

```py
        schema = StructType([
            StructField('a', StringType(), True),
            StructField('b', StringType(), True),
            StructField('c', StringType(), True),
            ...
        ])
        # rdd is the dstream from foreachRDD
        lines = sqlC.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

But I always get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`

Or

`TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'PAR1\x15\x04\x15\x1c\x15 L\x15\x02\x15\x04\x12\x00\x00\x0e4' in type <class 'str'>`

Comment: Do you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: @Divuneh we changed the approach and went for batch read with spark.read.parquet